# Button looks great in Chrome/FF but big fat fail in IE- can it be made to work?

Tags: html, css, button

See JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfnz2/

Any ideas good peoples of the interwebs?

Comment: This is going to sound lame, but I think your only option is to create an image and use that as a background to the button rather than using CSS3 for IE...

Comment: I did manage to get the effect with use of an SVG.  Not ideal but it worked.

Comment: Which version of IE do you want to cover?

Comment: Latest is fine but 7+ would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

On IE>6 use the below syntax:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1d805', endColorstr='#e7b223',GradientType=0 );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fac601', endColorstr='#f18e06',GradientType=0 );  //hover
```

It should work as expected!

Comment: Didn't do it, removes rounding and for some reason borders/shadowing as well.. unless I implemented wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Zfnz2/1/

Comment: border-radius is not supported in ie. There are some libraries to support some of the native css3 features like http://css3pie.com/, where you can mimic some css3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make IE work css wonders is by using [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

It can make wonders.